# Branch Prediction

Tags: mips

There is a branch sequence for 10 execution. A mispredicted branch results in a penalty of one stall cycle. How many stall cycles for a static predict not taken scheme.

How about for a one-bit dynamic prediction schemeif the prediction bit is 0?

T N T N T T N T N N

Comment: Sounds like homework. :)

You might get more traction on programmers.stackechange.com or cstheory.stackechange.com.

Answer (score 1):

[Note this looks like homework, so I'm just posting some guidelines on how things work, rather than directly answering what was asked.]

If all branches are statically predicted as not taken and there's a one-cycle penalty for a mis-predicted branch, then you're going to have a penalty every time a branch is taken (note that this is basically equivalent to having no branch prediction at all).

A one-bit predictor is basically going to just predict that the last action (taken or not) is repeated the next time that branch is encountered. In this case you get a penalty every time there's a transition between taken and not taken.

Comment: @user644441: half right. For the second, a transition in either direction will be penalized.

Comment: @user644441: That sounds a lot more reasonable to me anyway. Depending on what the initial prediction means, there might be another there.